# wldeploy problem - remote deploy not working

Tags: ant, weblogic, automated-deploy

I have the following ant configuration for remote deployment to weblogic.

```
<target name="deploy">
    <wldeploy name="${ant.project.name}.ear" user="${wls.username}" password="${wls.password}" adminurl="t3://${wls.hostname}:${wls.port}" action="deploy" source="myApp.ear" targets="${wls.server.name}" stage="true" verbose="true" upload="true" remote="true" debug="true"/>
</target>
```

I am facing the following error when I run the build file for this target:
BUILD FAILED
weblogic.management.ManagementException: [Deployer:149003]Unable to access application source information in 
'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-/W3C/DTD HTML 4.0 Draft/EN">/app/myApp.ear' for application 'myApp.ear'.

I believe I am not able to control the server location where the EAR files for deployment are staged. But why? 
The scripts seem to be working fine when the target is my peer machine(windows). Local deployments work as well. Is it reladted to unix env. or any weblogic server settings?

Comment: Is there an additional log message like "The specific error is: "

Comment: Here is the error josek:

The specific error is: No application files exist.

Comment: Here are the debug messages:

 [wldeploy] App root: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-\W3C\DTD HTML 4.0 Draft\EN">                       
 [wldeploy] App config: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-\W3C\DTD HTML 4.0 Draft\EN">\plan

Comment: As a test, if you were to deploy it manually once, does a 'redeploy' or 'undeploy' work?

Comment: my lead just got this working. looks like redeploy worked. Still not sure how. Will post updates shortly

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but using the weblogic.Deployer command. 
I solved it with the -name argument.

In your case, try replacing your name atribute as following:

name="${ant.project.name}.ear"

with:

name="${ant.project.name}"

The last should make work your deploy. Tell us if you could fix your problem with the Deploy tag.

Answer (score 0):

For those still struggling with this, make sure you include **upload="true"** in your wldeploy action.  This resolved the issue for me after many hours of struggling. For me, I was able to manually install into weblogic, yet the deployment kept giving the error:

> [Deployer:149003]Unable to access application source information...
> The specific error is: No application files exist

Below is an example wldeploy action with this setting included.

```
<wldeploy action="deploy" name="${name}" source="${deployDirEar}"   
  upload="true" user="${wl.user}" nostage="false" password="${wl.password}"     
  verbose="true" targets="${wl.adminserver.name}" adminurl="t3://${wl.host}:${wl.port}" />
```